# What are the Five Precepts?

Tags: five-precepts

And where are they found in the Pali Canon? I realize that this is a Straw Man question for the group but I would like to raise our visibility on  the Web and perhaps start our community wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the start of [Abhisanda Sutta (AN) 8:39](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.039.than.html):

> "Now, there are these five gifts, five great gifts — original, long-standing, traditional, ancient, unadulterated, unadulterated from the beginning — that are not open to suspicion, will never be open to suspicion, and are unfaulted by knowledgeable contemplatives & brahmans. Which five?
>
> "There is the case where a disciple of the noble ones, abandoning the taking of life, abstains from taking life.  In doing so, he gives freedom from danger, freedom from animosity, freedom from oppression to limitless numbers of beings. In giving freedom from danger, freedom from animosity, freedom from oppression to limitless numbers of beings, he gains a share in limitless freedom from danger, freedom from animosity, and freedom from oppression. […]
>
> "Furthermore, abandoning taking what is not given (stealing), the disciple of the noble ones abstains from taking what is not given. In doing so, he gives freedom from danger, freedom from animosity, freedom from oppression to limitless numbers of beings. […]
>
> "Furthermore, abandoning illicit sex, the disciple of the noble ones abstains from illicit sex. In doing so, he gives freedom from danger, freedom from animosity, freedom from oppression to limitless numbers of beings […]
>
> "Furthermore, abandoning lying, the disciple of the noble ones abstains from lying. In doing so, he gives freedom from danger, freedom from animosity, freedom from oppression to limitless numbers of beings. […]
>
> "Furthermore, abandoning the use of intoxicants, the disciple of the noble ones abstains from taking intoxicants. In doing so, he gives freedom from danger, freedom from animosity, freedom from oppression to limitless numbers of beings. […]

These are the "five precepts" or *pañca-sikkhāpada*. They are [frequently stated in English as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Precepts#Pali_training_rules):

1. I undertake the training rule to abstain from killing.
2. I undertake the training rule to abstain from taking what is not given.
3. I undertake the training rule to avoid sexual misconduct.
4. I undertake the training rule to abstain from false speech.
5. I undertake the training rule to abstain from fermented drink that causes heedlessness.

Which you can see along with the Eight Precepts at [The Five Precepts](http://bodhimonastery.org/the-five-and-eight-precepts.html)